# Meaning of 世界観に入り込む in the following sentence

Tags: meaning, words, verbs, expressions

The following sentence is taken from the afterword of the final volume of a manga:

> そんな風に名残惜しさを感じたり、**世界観に入り込んで**描くことができたのも、たくさんの人に読んでいただけて、キャラクターや作品が好きだと言ってもらえてものすごい励みになったことが一因だと思います。

I understand the general meaning of the sentence and its grammatical structure, but what is the meaning of 世界観に入り込んで描くことができた? In particular I don't know how to interpret the verb 入り込む. My attempt:

> I was able to draw understanding[?] the vision of the world [whose
>   vision?].

[Here you can see the original page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZeWt.jpg) for more context. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 世界観 refers to the world of *Samurai Drive* itself. The ["textbook" meaning of 世界観](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/123223/meaning/m0u/%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E8%A6%B3/) is something philosophical like "how to understand this world", such as "this world is supported by a giant turtle" or "this world is merely a large machine". However, 世界観 is very commonly used to refer to a fictional world itself or the exotic atmosphere of a fictional world. For example, you can say このゲームは古代エジプトの世界観を再現している, 鳥山明の世界観に浸る, SFの世界観, etc., and the difference between 世界観 and 世界 is very small in such cases.

So 世界観に入り込んで means "diving into the world (I created)", which figuratively means something like "as if I were in the world of *Samurai Drive* and saw the characters with my eyes".